# Can I obtain the expression of derivation by using Pytorch or Tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, pytorch, symbolic-math

My question is whether I could obtain the expression after I compute the derivation by using PyTorch or TensorFlow. For better understanding my question I provide an example below:

I have a function (x1, x2, and x3 are all the decision variables)

```
y = x1 + x1*x2 + x1*x3
```

The derivation of y in terms of x1 should be:

```
1 + x2 + x3
```

My question is, if I use PyTorch or TensorFlow do the computation, could I print out the expression of "1 + x2 + x3"? Very much appreciate if the codes are provided no matter by using PyTorch or TensorFlow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if it's possible in `Pytorch` or `Tensorflow`, but you can definitely do it using `SymPy` python library:

```
import sympy
x1 = sympy.symbols('x1')
x2 = sympy.symbols('x2')
x3 = sympy.symbols('x3')

y = x1 + x1*x2 + x1*x3
res = sympy.diff(y, x1)

print(res)
```

output:

```
x2 + x3 + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no.
Both PyTorch and TensorFlow will not provide you the symbolic expressions.
They can get you gradients though.

Here is a simple example in PyTorch:

```
x = torch.tensor([5.], requires_grad=True);
print(x) # tensor([5.], requires_grad=True)

y = 3*x**2
y.backward()
x.grad # tensor([30.])
```

How would you get this value 30 in plain python?

```
def y(x):
    return 3*x**2

x=5
print(y(x)) #75
e=0.01 #etha
g=(y(x+e)-y(x))/e 
print(g) # 30.0299
```

If you would use the smaller `etha` the more precise your gradient will be.

Comment: thank you very much, prosti. I has used the method pointed by @Anubhav Singh to achieve my goal. Thank you again!

Comment: No problem, glad you make it.

Comment: You may also go https://www.symbolab.com/ to get the symbolic computation.